# Sass files compiling twice

Tags: webpack, sass-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have following webpack configuration:

Rules:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: false
            }
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: false,
                processCssUrls: false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Plugins:

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].css'
})
```

When building and watching output with `SpeedMeasurePlugin` I get such output:

```
mini-css-extract-plugin, and 
css-loader, and 
sass-loader took 12.73 secs
  module count = 1
css-loader, and 
sass-loader took 12.66 secs
  module count = 1
```

Why does sass compile twice?

Answer (score 0):

It's MiniCssExtractPlugin running sass-loader twice. Not sure why.